# Add a realtime answers tab to stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, web-sockets, realtime-questions

We already have an awesome [realtime questions tab](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime) for every question that comes in over the whole network.

But in the spirit of [Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/), shouldn't we also have a realtime *answers* tab? It'd be really neat to see the answers coming through for each question in the network, and would give new users a sense of how helpful the QA model is.

---

My *real* motivation here, though, is spam detection. In [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq), we've already made a bot that runs regex on new question titles we get from the current realtime questions page. It works fairly well, and we'd like to expand to answers. We can't really do it with the API (too many requests to be useful). A page like this would necessitate a websocket, which we would then use for good.

Please?

Comment: It isn't exactly every question that comes in though. It is every active question (which means questions that have just been bumped, asked, edited, or *answered*). All it would really need would be a small piece of text that said what the recent activity was and "asked" or "answered" would then be able to be separated. If the title isn't enough, what did you envision the answered abstract pieces to look like?

Comment: Ideally we'd get an excerpt of the answer body, @TravisJ.

Comment: Just the similar two liner that questions get?

Comment: That'd be awesome. Even better would be the full answer, but that probably won't happen.

Comment: Related: [There should be a filter for new answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190086/). (That one is about filter.SE page, not SE homepage).

Comment: Loosely related: [Finding Questions with the Newest Answers anywhere on Site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235102/finding-questions-with-the-newest-answers-anywhere-on-site) (on-demand rather than real-time)

Comment: Related: https://github.com/KeyboardFire/Firefighter (feel free to fork and/or replace SmokeDetector with); works with all questions and answers, and gets the *full* body of posts, not just an excerpt.